# Dua Yastasheer and tawassul

Tags: ramadan, dua

I have been reciting these during Ramadan everyday and listening to it on YouTube and praying extra rakaats during rainfall does one have to continue reading till the dua is accepted? And is listening to the dua a good enough substitute for when it can't be read ie whilst driving or at work.

As they are said to be for the fulfillment of all legitimate desires, should one understand the dua has been rejected if not granted after 3 recitations (I say 3, but have been reciting dua indefinitely)

(Salatul hajaat?)